# Simple javascript for loop, strange behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

I've got a fairly simple loop that supposed to run through all elements in the document and stick the ones with a class containing "toggler" in an array. [Here's a JSFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/RyxKS/16/)

As you can see, there are obviously 3 togglers defined but the loop is only counting two.  It seems to be skipping any element directly following a positive match, but I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: unfortunately no, this is being used in an extremely outdated and restrictive environment (IE 6 even!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `g` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RyxKS/17/):

```
  var togglerTest = /toggler/;
```

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

meaning it will match every other toggler due to the `g`.

Comment: D'oh.. that did the trick, although I'm not 100% sure why.  I'm fairly new with regular expressions